# Python - Cannot find a specific date in a list of dates

Tags: python

I have a list with all the dates in a year. I'm trying to find today's date in the list.

Sample File Calendar2020.txt

```
09/15/2020
09/16/2020
09/17/2020
09/18/2020
09/19/2020
09/20/2020
09/21/2020
09/22/2020
09/23/2020
09/24/2020
09/25/2020
09/26/2020
09/27/2020
09/28/2020
09/29/2020
09/30/2020
10/01/2020
10/02/2020
10/03/2020
10/04/2020
10/05/2020
10/06/2020
```

The code is:

```
calendarData = open('C:/Users/micha/source/repos/Test_Pass_Variables2Function/Calendar2020.txt').readlines()

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
date = current_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

for i in range(0,366):
    if(date==calendarData[i]):
        break
    else:
        print(i,end="  ")
        print("date", date, end=" ")
        print(calendarData[i])
        i=i+1
```

Console output

```
269  date 09/29/2020 09/26/2020
270  date 09/29/2020 09/27/2020
271  date 09/29/2020 09/28/2020
272  date 09/29/2020 09/29/2020
273  date 09/29/2020 09/30/2020
274  date 09/29/2020 10/01/2020
275  date 09/29/2020 10/02/2020
```

The comparion test isn't working. Line 272 should break

Comment: Can you post a few lines from your `.txt` file. It's impossible to test your code without a file.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  Unless you have isolated the problem to your file input, you should hard-code the data to remove that factor.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your entries in the `calendarData` includes a trailing newline, so it will never match the `date` value. just strip the newline, like this:

```
for i in range(0,366):
    if(date==calendarData[i].strip('\n')):
        break
    else:
        print(i,end="  ")
        print("date", date, end=" ")
        print(calendarData[i])
        i=i+1
```

Comment: hmmm...really?...I would think that would have given him double-spaced output then, since his final `print` should add its own newline.  But that certainly would explain the problem.  I'm just not sure why you're confident that that extra newline is there. - oh, guess it's a function of `readlines()`.  Does that leave the newline at the end of each line?

Comment: I get double spaced output when I run the posted code.

Comment: Ah!  Great!  I was just confirming that `readlines()` does in fact leave the newlines in there, so you're 100% correct here.  +1 from me.